# Custom admin module not working

Tags: magento-1.9, module, custom

I have created a custom module but it's not working, I am unable to see any menu in cms menu.here is my code:-
**1.config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Paras_Missingmeta>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Paras_Missingmeta>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <paras_missingmeta>
        <class>Paras_Missingmeta_Helper</class>
      </paras_missingmeta>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <missingmeta>
        <class>Paras_Missingmeta_Block</class>
      </missingmeta>
    </blocks>
  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <missingmeta>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
          <module>Paras_Missingmeta</module>
          <frontName>admin_missingmeta</frontName>
        </args>
      </missingmeta>
    </routers>
  </admin>
  <adminhtml>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <missingmeta>
          <file>missingmeta.xml</file>
        </missingmeta>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

**2.adminhtml.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <menu>
      <cms>
        <children>
         <paras_missingmeta module="paras_missingmeta">
        <title>Missing meta keys</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
          <missingproduct module="paras_missingmeta">
            <title>Product Meta Keys</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <action>admin_missingmeta/adminhtml_index</action>
          </missingproduct>
           <missingcat module="paras_missingmeta">
            <title>Category Meta Keys</title>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            <action>admin_missingmeta/adminhtml_cat</action>
          </missingcat>
            <missingcms module="paras_missingmeta">
            <title>CMS Meta Keys</title>
            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
            <action>admin_missingmeta/adminhtml_cms</action>
          </missingcms>
        </children>
      </paras_missingmeta>
        </children>
      </cms>
    </menu>
    <acl>
      <resources>
        <all>
          <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
          <children>
            <missingmeta translate="title" module="missingmeta">
              <title>Missingmeta</title>
              <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
              <children>
          <missingmetabackend translate="title">
            <title>Backend Page Title</title>
          </missingmetabackend>
              </children>
            </missingmeta>
          </children>
        </admin>
      </resources>
    </acl>
 </config>
```

If need any other files then i can post here.
both files are being loaded i have checked it.

Comment: Since APPSEC-1034, admin routers not using the secure URL should be avoided. Please replace it following the Magento recommendations : http://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details

Comment: not working i have checked

Comment: I have created the simple module Paras_Missingmeta and used your code for `app/code/local/Paras/Missingmeta/etc/config.xml` and `app/code/local/Paras/Missingmeta/etc/adminhtml.xml` files. The menu has been appeared under CMS. Recheck if you created the module correctly. Clear the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i test your code there was not error in that. just check the cache is disabled and your module is listed in `system/configuration/advanced` and you add the `Helper/Data.php` class

app/etc/modules/Paras_Missingmeta.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Paras_Missingmeta>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Paras_Missingmeta>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Paras/Missingmeta/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Paras_Missingmeta>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Paras_Missingmeta>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <paras_missingmeta>
        <class>Paras_Missingmeta_Helper</class>
      </paras_missingmeta>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <missingmeta>
        <class>Paras_Missingmeta_Block</class>
      </missingmeta>
    </blocks>
  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <missingmeta>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
          <module>Paras_Missingmeta</module>
          <frontName>admin_missingmeta</frontName>
        </args>
      </missingmeta>
    </routers>
  </admin>
  <adminhtml>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <missingmeta>
          <file>missingmeta.xml</file>
        </missingmeta>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Paras/Missingmeta/adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <menu>
      <cms>
        <children>
         <paras_missingmeta module="paras_missingmeta">
        <title>Missing meta keys</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
          <missingproduct module="paras_missingmeta">
            <title>Product Meta Keys</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <action>admin_missingmeta/adminhtml_index</action>
          </missingproduct>
           <missingcat module="paras_missingmeta">
            <title>Category Meta Keys</title>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            <action>admin_missingmeta/adminhtml_cat</action>
          </missingcat>
            <missingcms module="paras_missingmeta">
            <title>CMS Meta Keys</title>
            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
            <action>admin_missingmeta/adminhtml_cms</action>
          </missingcms>
        </children>
      </paras_missingmeta>
        </children>
      </cms>
    </menu>
    <acl>
      <resources>
        <all>
          <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
          <children>
            <missingmeta translate="title" module="missingmeta">
              <title>Missingmeta</title>
              <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
              <children>
          <missingmetabackend translate="title">
            <title>Backend Page Title</title>
          </missingmetabackend>
              </children>
            </missingmeta>
          </children>
        </admin>
      </resources>
    </acl>
 </config>
```

app/code/local/Paras/Missingmeta/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php

class Paras_Missingmeta_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{


 }
```

Comment: Got is there was a problem with my config file it was <active>active</active>.